# How to add NSViewController to a responder chain?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller, nsresponder

I'm having hard time understanding and finding info about how to make NSViewController accept key and mouse events. I read somewhere that in order to register these events in NSViewController it should be added to a responder chain, but I can't find the answer how to properly do this.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you done so far?  What do you find when you run a search for [objective-c] [osx] nsview mouse events?

Comment: I have a custom view controller which is a subclass of NSViewController. This controller has a property which is a NSView. The property gets set through nib file (through IBOutlet). I know that I can subclass NSView, and implement mouse/key events there, and pass them through notification to my controller...or use setNextResponder there (as Michael said below). However, I'm curious  if I can somehow ad controller to responder chain without subclassing from nsview.

Comment: Claus Jørgensen is correct in that not all view controllers get added to the responder chain in all situations - for example if the view controller itself isn't added as a child view controller to a parent controller (but its view is somehow added to the view hierarchy through other means), that view controller will not become part of the responder chain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a nice [tutorial found at CocoaWithLove.com](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/better-integration-for-nsviewcontroller.html).

Summed up:  you'll create a subclass of NSView (e.g. "EugeneView") and then that subclass will have some extra methods in it, such as "`setNextResponder`" and "`setViewController`".  And doing these two methods should get your NSViewController integrated into the responder chain.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Michael! can I somehow add viewController to the responder chain without subclassing from nsview?

Comment: @EugeneGordin: yes, seem my answer below

Answer (score 7):

Manually patching in the `NSViewController` into the responder chain isn't necessary anymore as of OS X 10.10 Yosemite. According to [WWDC '14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-212/), "they're automatically wired up in the responder chain right after their view."

Comment: This is incorrect, not all view controllers are automatically wired up in the responder chain.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: Can you base your comment/downvote on a particular example, please?
Also I would like to invite you to have a [look at the above video, 20:33](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-212/).

Comment: For OSX 10.10 and 10.11 and up I can confirm this works OK and is probably the preferred answer.

Answer (score 6):

Or if, as is the case most of the time, your controller's view is simply a generic container, insert your controller in the responder chain between its view and its subviews. This can be done with these lines of code in your controller's `awakeFromNib:`

Obj-C:

```
[self setNextResponder:self.view];

for (NSView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    [subview setNextResponder:self]; 
}
```

Swift:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.nextResponder = self.view
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        subview.nextResponder = self
    }
}
```

No subclassing needed.

Comment: Using this method can cause *** CFHash() called with NULL *** crashes when targeting 10.8.5

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer because it's easier (I couldn't get the accepted answer to work on the first attempt either). Thanks.

Comment: how do you do this in swift in the class ViewController:  NSViewController?

Answer (score 1):

While debugging. I noticed the NSViewController `view` does not accept the first responder.

You can confirm this by printing `print(viewController.view) //false`

for NSViewController to be added to the responder chain, its view must `acceptFirstReponder`. This could easily be done by creating an extension of NSView and overriding its `acceptFirstResponder`

```
extension NSView{
    //making view acceptFirstResponder by default,
    //this will enable NSViewController receive responder event dispatched into responder chain
    open override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool{return true}
}
```

With this, your controller will added to the responder chain and will receive all responder events.

My explanation may not be too accurate as I am new to Cocoa. but the solution does work perfectly well.

I did this to resolve issue of my ViewController not receiving `onKeyDown` event.