# validateMenuItem on NSViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsviewcontroller, nsresponder

Is it possible to have validateMenuItem work with NSViewControllers?  The docs say NSViewController is a subclass of NSResponder so I would think it would participate in the responder chain, but I have never been able to get it to work.  I can make it work with NSView, no problem.

The particular use case I have is a menu item in the MainMenu.xib, connected to First Responder. The selector from my view controller subclass shows up in the First Responder pop up list of selectors in MainMenu, so I would think it would work, but it doesn't.  The validateMenuItem method of my subclass is never called.  (The one in the app delegate is called, but not for the item which is connected to First Responder.)

Comment: NSViewControllers are part of the responder chain since OS X 10.10. If you target earlier versions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061052/how-to-add-nsviewcontroller-to-a-responder-chain

Comment: Is the NSViewController in question the `target` (or in its hierarchy) of the item you're validating? If not, you'll never get that event.