# Swift - Capture keydown from NSViewController

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to capture keyevents in my little app.

**What I have done:**

```
class ViewController : NSViewController {
...
  override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if theEvent.keyCode == 124 {
            println("abc")
        } else {
            println("abcd")
        }
    }

    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

...
}
```

**What happens:**

When a key pressed, the `Funk` sound effect plays.

I've seen many posts talking about how this is a delegate the belongs to `NSView` and `NSViewController` does not have access. But the `keydown` function `override` auto completes in a class of type `NSViewController` leading me to believe that this is wrong.

Comment: Which object is the first responder?

Comment: To eliminate the "Funk Sound" just return nil instead of the event, in the closure. I use the localMonitor approach.

Comment: One caveat muting the funk sound this way is that you don't forward the keyDown event to other parts of the app, like cmd+q, to mitigate this you could return nil only on keyDown events you want to target, if you want to target a,b,c keystrokes then return nil only on these keyStrokes etc.

Comment: the signature has changed on swift 4<br/>override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {}<br/>

Comment: it works fine but it drops support of built-in combinations like `CMD+W` to close the window or `Ctrl+CMD+F` to maximize the window

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged) {
            self.flagsChanged(with: $0)
            return $0
        }
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
            self.keyDown(with: $0)
            return $0
        }
    }
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        switch event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) {
        case [.command] where event.characters == "l",
             [.command, .shift] where event.characters == "l":
            print("command-l or command-shift-l")
        default:
            break
        }
        textField.stringValue = "key = " + (event.charactersIgnoringModifiers
            ?? "")
        textField.stringValue += "\ncharacter = " + (event.characters ?? "")
    }
    override func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent) {
        switch event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) {
        case [.shift]:
            print("shift key is pressed")
        case [.control]:
            print("control key is pressed")
        case [.option] :
            print("option key is pressed")
        case [.command]:
            print("Command key is pressed")
        case [.control, .shift]:
            print("control-shift keys are pressed")
        case [.option, .shift]:
            print("option-shift keys are pressed")
        case [.command, .shift]:
            print("command-shift keys are pressed")
        case [.control, .option]:
            print("control-option keys are pressed")
        case [.control, .command]:
            print("control-command keys are pressed")
        case [.option, .command]:
            print("option-command keys are pressed")
        case [.shift, .control, .option]:
            print("shift-control-option keys are pressed")
        case [.shift, .control, .command]:
            print("shift-control-command keys are pressed")
        case [.control, .option, .command]:
            print("control-option-command keys are pressed")
        case [.shift, .command, .option]:
            print("shift-command-option keys are pressed")
        case [.shift, .control, .option, .command]:
            print("shift-control-option-command keys are pressed")
        default:
            print("no modifier keys are pressed")
        }
    }
}
```

---

To get rid of the purr sound when pressing the character keys you need to subclass your view, override the method performKeyEquivalent and return true.

```
import Cocoa

class View: NSView {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sgtypovuf720t5/keyDownViewController.zip?dl=1)

Comment: How can you tell if you're using swift 1.2 or 2.0

Comment: This works in Swift 2.x - I can get the keyDown event in my override func keyDown() event code but I still get the "Funk" sound how do you eliminate the "Funk" sound?

Comment: Leo Dabus - are you suggesting I use your invisible button idea to eliminate the "Funk" sound for keyDown event?

Comment: My window (view) has several "Label" fields (Labels are really just NSTextFields).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103537/discussion-between-neal-davis-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @LeoDabus do you still have a sample project?

Comment: @LeoDabus got it! ^^

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question  "how to get the controller to capture the keyboard events?" The controller should be in the responder chain somewhere - as long as other objects in the responder chain don't gobble up the event first *and* the controller can accept/become the first responder (by overriding the appropriate properties/methods) it should get the events.

Comment: @leoDabus One Question: I try to capture "shift ArrowUp" with the function keyDown, but I don't get it. The event goes to default: . What's the correct case pattern?

Comment: The flagsChanged should detect the shift press. The arrowup keycode is 126. I am not sure why it wouldn't detect that combination. Are you saying that when shift is down it doesn't print `"shift key is pressed"`?

Comment: @mica https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsg304w91dmruub/CaptureKeyDown.zip?dl=1

Comment: You're all forgetting here that you have to unregister the monitor again after you are done! Take the return value from `addLocalMonitorForEvents` and call `removeMonitor` in `deinit`!

Comment: Works great, but be cautious about the strong reference inside the block, because it would cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 21):

**Swift4**

Just found a solution for the very same problem, Swift4. The idea behind that: if the pressed key was handled by a custom logic, the handler shall return nil, otherwise the (unhandled) event...

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // ...
      NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
         if self.myKeyDown(with: $0) {
            return nil
         } else {
            return $0
         }
      }
   }
   func myKeyDown(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
      // handle keyDown only if current window has focus, i.e. is keyWindow
      guard let locWindow = self.view.window,
         NSApplication.shared.keyWindow === locWindow else { return false }
      switch Int( event.keyCode) {
      case kVK_Escape:
         // do what you want to do at "Escape"
         return true
      default: 
         return false
      }
   }
}
```

And here we are: no Purr  / Funk sound when key is pressed...

[Update] Added check of keyWindow. Without this, keyDown() is fired even if another view/window contains the first responder...

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me to get rid of the purr sound

Comment: Is there an easy way to detect long press (press and hold) of a key?

Answer (score 10):

I was trying to find an answer for swift 3, here is what worked for me:

## Swift 3

```
import Cocoa

// We subclass an NSView

class MainView: NSView {

    // Allow view to receive keypress (remove the purr sound)
    override var acceptsFirstResponder : Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Override the NSView keydown func to read keycode of pressed key
    override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        Swift.print(theEvent.keyCode)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I manage to get it work from subclass of `NSWindowController`

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        print("keyCode is \(theEvent.keyCode)")
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
import Cocoa

protocol WindowControllerDelegate {
    func keyDown(aEvent: NSEvent)
}

class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    var delegate: WindowControllerDelegate?

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        delegate = window?.contentViewController as! ViewController
    }
    override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        delegate?.keyDown(theEvent)
    }

}
```

and ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, WindowControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        textField.stringValue = "key = " + (theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers
            ?? "")
        textField.stringValue += "\ncharacter = " + (theEvent.characters ?? "")
        textField.stringValue += "\nmodifier = " + theEvent.modifierFlags.rawValue.description
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let kLeftArrowKeyCode:  UInt16  = 123
    let kRightArrowKeyCode: UInt16  = 124
    let kDownArrowKeyCode:  UInt16  = 125
    let kUpArrowKeyCode:    UInt16  = 126
    
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
              switch event.keyCode {
              case kLeftArrowKeyCode:
                  print("left")
                  break
              case kRightArrowKeyCode:
                  print("right")
                  break
              case kDownArrowKeyCode:
                  print("down")
                  break
              case kUpArrowKeyCode:
                  print("up")
                  break
              default:
                  print("other")
                  super.keyDown(with: event)
                  break
              }
              print("Key with number: \(event.keyCode) was pressed")
    }
```