# In the NsView, how to judge whether the user holding down the Shift key

Tags: swift, macos

Everybody is good, I in their own ViewController, I want to be able to determine whether to user is holding down the Shift key keyboard or the Command key.Please familiar friend told me that I should how to implement.Thank you very much!

Comment: Key down on NSView?  It doesn't sound like a good question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this could be to use a *local event monitor* ([described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3)).

This method monitors all events of the type you ask it to. So for instance you could use it to get notified of all keypresses like so:

```
NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
    self.keyDown(with: $0)
    return $0
}
```

This will give you instances of `NSEvent` every time a key is pressed (every time the key is pressed down actually, there is also a .keyUp which is triggered when the key is released).

The [NSEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent) class then has a set of `ModifierFlags` which you can query and see whether one or more of these modifiers has been pressed alongside the key. So, your `keyDown` method (which overrides the one from `NSResponder`) could do something like this:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift) {
        print("Shift pressed")
    }
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
        print("Command pressed")
    }
    super.keyDown(with: event)
}
```

### Complete Example

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
            self.keyDown(with: $0)
            return $0
        }
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift) {
            print("Shift pressed")
        }
        if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
            print("Command pressed")
        }
        super.keyDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

### See Also

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32447474/4063602)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the case, but this method does not monitor the Shift key and the Command key. Did you miss something?

Comment: @DivenLee I've changed from `.control` to `.command` and can now see the following: If I launch the app and press s for instance, nothing happens, if I press shift + s I can see "Shift pressed" in the console. If I press command + s I can see "Command pressed" in the console. Do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: I have already found the reason, this belongs to the flagsChanged rewritten, different events.Thank you very much for additional reference, then give me the answer.thank you